# Regular Expression In Android for Password Field

Tags: android, regex

How can i validating the `EditText` with `Regex` by allowing particular characters .
My condition is :

Password Rule:

1. **One capital letter**
2. **One number**
3. **One symbol** `(@,$,%,&,#,)` whatever normal symbols that are acceptable.

   May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Try this may helps

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$
```

**How it works?**

```
^                 # start-of-string
(?=.*[0-9])       # a digit must occur at least once
(?=.*[a-z])       # a lower case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[A-Z])       # an upper case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])  # a special character must occur at least once you can replace with your special characters
(?=\\S+$)          # no whitespace allowed in the entire string
.{4,}             # anything, at least six places though
$                 # end-of-string
```

**How to Implement?**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
        Button btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);

        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (isValidPassword(editText.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "InValid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isValidPassword(final String password) {

        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;

        final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";

        pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

        return matcher.matches();

    }

}
```

Comment: @BirajZalavadia do you know how to include ( " ) i.e. double quotes in my regex special characters list. If i include '' its getting an error.

Comment: What does `.{4,}` mean? It has a 4 but says "at least six places though", what does this mean?

Comment: Why forbid whitespace, though?

Answer (score 17):

None of the above worked for me.

What worked for me:

```
fun isValidPasswordFormat(password: String): Boolean {
    val passwordREGEX = Pattern.compile("^" +
        "(?=.*[0-9])" +         //at least 1 digit
        "(?=.*[a-z])" +         //at least 1 lower case letter
        "(?=.*[A-Z])" +         //at least 1 upper case letter
        "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +      //any letter
        "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" +    //at least 1 special character
        "(?=\\S+$)" +           //no white spaces
        ".{8,}" +               //at least 8 characters
        "$");
    return passwordREGEX.matcher(password).matches()
}
```

Source: [Coding in Flow](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/validate-email-password-regular-expressions)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 14):

And for the **Kotlin** lovers :

```
fun isValidPassword(password: String?) : Boolean {
   password?.let {
       val passwordPattern = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$"
       val passwordMatcher = Regex(passwordPattern)

       return passwordMatcher.find(password) != null
   } ?: return false
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this.

```
(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])([@$%&#])[0-9a-zA-Z]{4,}$/)


(/^
(?=.*\d)                //should contain at least one digit
(?=.*[@$%&#])           //should contain at least one special char
(?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case
[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}         //should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters
$/)
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry . Someone person down vote my questions & include all answer . I did't do this . I up voted your answer . Please vote up this question .

Comment: the second last line means "8"  chars or "4" ??

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
try {
    if (subjectString.matches("^(?=.*[@$%&#_()=+?»«<>£§€{}\\[\\]-])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d).*(?<=.{4,})$")) {
        // String matched entirely
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

---

Requirements:

```
(?=.*[@\$%&#_()=+?»«<>£§€{}.[\]-]) -> must have at least 1 special character
(?=.*[A-Z])   -> Must have at least 1 upper case letter
(?=.*[a-z])   -> Must have at least 1 lower case letter
(?=.*\\d)     -> Must have at least 1 digit
(?<=.{4,})$") -> Must be equal or superior to 4 chars.
```

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the answers already given, I would suggest a different route for identifying special characters and also would split up the check for the different rules.

First splitting it up: Instead of making one big rule, split it and check every rule separately, so that you are able to provide feedback to the user as to what exactly is wrong with his password. This might take a bit longer but in something like a password check-up this will not be noticeable. Also, this way the conditions are more readable.

Secondly, instead of checking for a list of special characters, you could flip it and check if the password contains any characters that are neither letters of the Latin alphabet (a-zA-Z) nor digits (0-9). That way you don't "forget" special characters. For example, let's say you check specifically but in your check you forget a character like "{”. With this approach, this can't happen. You can extend that list by things you don't consider to be special characters explicitly, for example a space. In Kotlin, it would look like this:

```
val errorText = when {
    /* Rule 1 */
    !password.contains(Regex("[A-Z]")) -> "Password must contain one capital letter"
    /* Rule 2 */
    !password.contains(Regex("[0-9]")) -> "Password must contain one digit"
    /* Rule 3, not counting space as special character */
    !password.contains(Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]")) -> "Password must contain one special character"
    else -> null
}
```

Depending on your encoding, you can also use regex and define your special characters using ranges of hex codes like:

```
Reges("[\x00-\x7F]")
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm too late to answer but still it may help you.

I've worked with `Kotlin`.

Add following function.

```
private fun isValidPassword(password: String): Boolean {
    val pattern: Pattern
    val matcher: Matcher
    val specialCharacters = "-@%\\[\\}+'!/#$^?:;,\\(\"\\)~`.*=&\\{>\\]<_"
    val PASSWORD_REGEX = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$specialCharacters])(?=\\S+$).{8,20}$"
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_REGEX)
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password)
    return matcher.matches()
}
```

**Function description:**

- (?=.*[0-9]) # a digit must occur at least once
- (?=.*[a-z]) # a lower case letter must occur at least once
- (?=.*[A-Z]) # an upper case letter must occur at least once
- (?=.*[-@%[}+'!/#$^?:;,(")~`.*=&{>]<_]) # a special character must occur at least once
  replace with your special characters
- (?=\S+$) # no whitespace allowed in the entire string .{8,} #
  anything, at least six places though

You can modify it as needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the class `Patern` than `Matcher` for every checking format.

I give you an exemple of use :

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myEmailString);
        if (!myEmailString.contains("@") || !matcher.matches()) {
            // error in the email : do staff 
            myEmailView.setError("invalid email !");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most common password validation is

1. At least 8 character
2. Require numbers
3. Require special character
4. Require uppercase letters
5. Require lowercase letters

Regex:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\\/%§"&“|`´}{°><:.;#')(@_$"!?*=^-]).{8,}$
```

Kotlin code:

```
    val PASSWORD_REGEX_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\\/%§"&“|`´}{°><:.;#')(@_$"!?*=^-]).{8,}$"

    fun isValidPassword(password: String?): Boolean {
        val pattern: Pattern =
            Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_REGEX_PATTERN)
        val matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(password)
        return matcher.matches()
    }
```

online regex validator to check it:

- https://regex101.com/
- https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers are good, but the implementation of special characters were a bit too messy for my taste. I used Unicode for special characters instead.

I used special characters specified in the [OWASP website](https://owasp.org/www-community/password-special-characters).

**Kotlin:**

```kotlin
val SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX =
    "?=.*[\\u0020-\\u002F\\u003A-\\u0040\\u005B-\\u0060\\u007B-\\u007E]"
val PASSWORD_REGEX =
    "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])($SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX).{8,}\$"

fun isValidPassword(password: String) = Pattern.matches(PASSWORD_REGEX, password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (validatePassword())
  {
   // if valid
  }

private boolean validatePassword() {
    String passwordInput =  password.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!passwordInput.matches(".*[0-9].*")) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Password should contain at least 1 digit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if (!passwordInput.matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Password should contain at least 1 lower case letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if (!passwordInput.matches(".*[A-Z].*")) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Password should contain at least 1 upper case letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if (!passwordInput.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Password should contain a letter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else if (!passwordInput.matches( ".{8,}")) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Password should contain 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun passwordValidate(password1: String, password2: String): Boolean {
    when {
        password1.length < 9 -> {
            textView2.text = "Password Has To Be At Least 9 Characters Long"
            return false
        }
        !password1.matches(".*[A-Z].*".toRegex()) -> {
            textView2.text = "Password Must Contain 1 Upper-case Character"
            return false
        }
        !password1.matches(".*[a-z].*".toRegex()) -> {
            textView2.text = "Password Must Contain 1 Lower-case Character"
            return false
        }
        !password1.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*+=/?].*".toRegex()) -> {
            textView2.text = "Password Must Contain 1 Symbol"
            return false
        }
        password1 != password2 -> {
            textView3.text = "Passwords Don't Match"
            return false
        }
        else -> return true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple way to check it without using regex in Kotlin.
It will check for password length >= 8, at least one capital letter, one small letter, one number, and one special character.

```
fun isValidPassword(pass:String):Boolean{
    if(pass.length<8) return false
    var u = 0
    var l = 0
    var d = 0
    var s = 0
    for (char in pass){
        if(char.isUpperCase()) u++
        else if(char.isLowerCase()) l++
        else if(char.isDigit()) d++
        else if(char in "@#$%^&+=_.") s++
    }
    if(u==0|| l==0 || s==0 || d==0) return false
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st above answer is correct but if you want password Regex separately validation. Try this for e.g.:

```
private boolean isPasswordHasSymbol (String password) {
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.find();
}

private boolean isPasswordHasUppercase (String password) {
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*[A-Z])";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    return matcher.find();
}
```