# Password Patteren does not matched with the Matcher class

Tags: android, passwords, pattern-matching, matcher

My Password should be Like :

"**Password should contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one digit and one special character with minimum eight character length**"

The Pattern I have used is : `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,}`

So, I have created a function as below in my Constant.java file :

```
public static Boolean passwordMatcher(TextInputLayout edtText,String string) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\\\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(edtText.getEditText().getText().toString());
    boolean isMatched = matcher.matches();
    if (isMatched) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!isMatched) {
        edtText.setErrorEnabled(true);
        edtText.setError("" + string);
        edtText.setFocusable(true);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in my MainActivity.java file I have checked for validation as below :

```
if (!Constant.passwordMatcher(edtPassword, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_activity_signup_password_invalid))) {
    return;
}
```

But, I am not getting success even if I have tried : '**Jaimin123#**' as a my password. 
Always getting error set in my TextInputLayout.

What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214434/regular-expression-in-android-for-password-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password must be 8 characters including 1 uppercase letter, 1 special character, alphanumeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477906/password-must-be-8-characters-including-1-uppercase-letter-1-special-character)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression In Android for Password Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214434/regular-expression-in-android-for-password-field)

Comment: Your regex is OK, you need to replace `\\\\d` with `\\d`

Comment: you are right, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below regex for password match.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?!.*\s).{8,}$
```

This regex will check for below rules:

1. At least one upper case letter
2. At least one lower case letter
3. At least one digit
4. At least one special character
5. Minimum 8 in length

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@#!%*?&]).{8,}$
```

If you don't want white space in password include `(?=\S+$)` also

Comment: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 50:
                                                                 ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&]){8,}$

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public void checkPattern(String password) {     
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W).{8,}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
    boolean isMatched = matcher.matches();
    System.out.println(isMatched);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public boolean matchesPattern(String password) {        
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?!.*\s).{8,}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```