# how to set regex in EditText with Android two way binding?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

Hello I wonder how to set regex in EditText with Android two way binding

my regex

```
val VALID_PASSWOLD_REGEX_ALPHA_NUM: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z[0-9]$@$!%*#?&]{8,32}$")
```

my viewModel

```
val passwordText = MutableLiveData<String>("")
```

my xml

```
<EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> signUpViewModel.onPasswordChanged(text)}"
                android:hint="@string/sign_up_password"
                android:text="@={signUpViewModel.passwordText}"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_text" />
```

My short thought is that it should be received from onTextChange and processed, but I can't think of a better way, so I ask this question

Could you please introduce me another way?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214434/regular-expression-in-android-for-password-field

Comment: It's a completely different story, I'm not asking because I can't use regex, it's about an efficient way to use regex, and that's in live data two-way binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did it using android:onTextChanged Thanks